# Implementing upload progress bar with responds_to_parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, progress-bar

I am trying to implement an upload progress bar for an ajax file upload implementation using responds_to_parent(http://responds-to-parent.googlecode.com/svn/trunk).

I basically have made use of responds_to_parent plugin as I am using an old rails version of 2.0.2 for project specific purposes. I am also making use of Ruby 1.8.7

I was able to find something to suit my requirement: http://www.bram.us/2008/07/11/ror-progress-bar-helper/ , but due to insufficient readme/support for this plugin I haven't been able to get this working yet.

The Rails version of this plugin has originated from:- http://www.bram.us/projects/js_bramus/jsprogressbarhandler/

Can you kindly suggest other options which could come to my rescue, something(JS) that would help me integrate the functionality with the responds_to_parent plugin.

Thanks..